# Does clang-format recognize new NS_CLOSED_ENUM Objective-C macro?

Tags: objective-c, clang-format

As of Xcode 10.2, there is a new macro for specifying enums in Objective-C, `NS_CLOSED_ENUM`. Using this in place of `NS_ENUM` is required, to allow those enums to be used *in Swift*, as if they were *declared in Swift* (meaning without either requiring an `@unknown` handler in switch statements, or getting a warning). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55401993/45813) for more.

It appears that clang-format has not caught up to this new reality, and won't recognize

```
typedef NS_CLOSED_ENUM(...
```

the same as it does

```
typedef NS_ENUM(...
```

Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [these commits](https://reviews.llvm.org/D65012) (around July 2019), clang-format apparently does support `NS_CLOSED_ENUM`.