# New Swift 5 warnings for Objective-C enums: how to get rid of them?

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift5, xcode10.2

As of Xcode 10.2, when using enums I've defined in Objective-C, but in a Swift 5 switch statement, I get the following warning, even if I've exhausted all the possible enum values.

```
Switch covers known cases, but 'MyObjectiveCEnumName' may have additional 
unknown values
```

Xcode is telling me I should fix this by

```
Handle unknown values using "@unknown default"
```

Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

---

#### Example

Objective-C enum

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, CardColor) {
  CardColorBlack,
  CardColorRed
};
```

Swift 5 switch statement

```
var cardColor: CardColor = .black

switch (cardColor) {
case .black:
  print("black")
case .red:
  print("red")
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### TL;DR

If you want Objective-C enums to be treated just like Swift ones, you now need to declare them using a different macro, `NS_CLOSED_ENUM`, versus the old `NS_ENUM`. Changing this will make the warning disappear.

The example above would become

```
typedef NS_CLOSED_ENUM(NSUInteger, CardColor) {
  CardColorBlack,
  CardColorRed
};
```

#### Deets

From the [Swift 5 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2):

> In Swift 5 mode, switches over enumerations that are declared in Objective-C or that come from system frameworks are required to handle unknown cases—cases that might be added in the future, or that may be defined privately in an Objective-C implementation file. Formally, Objective-C allows storing any value in an enumeration as long as it fits in the underlying type. These unknown cases can be handled by using the new @unknown default case, which still provides warnings if any known cases are omitted from the switch. They can also be handled using a normal default case.
>
> If you’ve defined your own enumeration in Objective-C and you don’t need clients to handle unknown cases, you can use the NS_CLOSED_ENUM macro instead of NS_ENUM. The Swift compiler recognizes this and doesn’t require switches to have a default case.